# Correct way of creating DTO

Tags: java

When I create a Data transfer Object (DTO) which I use to store user input data to manager layer, I have a doubt that I'm doing it in correct way.

For example

Scenario one

```
public class Person{

    private String name;
    private int age;  // primitive type
    private double weight; // primitive type

}
```

Scenario 2

```
public class Person{

    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    private Double weight;

}
```

in this case what is the best scenario that I can use and what are the factors that I should think about when decide on each scenarios. Kindly advice me.

Comment: what you want to do with the DTO?

Comment: Store user inputs and pass it to manager layer

Comment: Data Transfer object - I edited my question with those information

Comment: To avoid `null` traps just add a if check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can use a primitive type, I would use a primitive type. Not just for performance reasons but to make it clear that `null` is not a valid value.

If you have a value which can be `null`, use a wrapper.

Also if you can make the fields `final` I would do so as well as this avoids questions of mutability and thread safety.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I prefer the primitives in order to avoid the `null` traps.